# LWJGL imput a Vector3f Array into Fragment Shader

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I'm currently working on a LWJGL 2 game. I'M using the libraries from https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics (for example the Texture and ShaderProgram class). I am aware, that you can get a limited amount of lights to be rendered in your shader, but I didn't find any solution to make the lighting more dynamic and efficient.
I want to pass a Vector3f[] lights into the .frag file as uniform vec3 lights[]. How can I do that? Any other idea of dynamicly changing the number of lights im shading? Here's the code of the fragment shader:

```
    //attributes from vertex shader
    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying vec2 vTexCoord;

    uniform sampler2D u_texture;  
    uniform sampler2D u_normals;   


    //the array should be inserted as:

    uniform vec3 Lights[];  

    uniform int numOfLights;          
    uniform vec2 Resolution;     
    uniform float Rotation;      
    //uniform vec3 LightPos;   
    uniform vec4 LightColor;      
    uniform vec4 AmbientColor;  
    uniform vec3 Falloff;      

    void main() {

    vec4 sumColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

    for(int i = 0;i < numOfLights;i++){
    vec3 LightPos = Lights[i];

    vec4 DiffuseColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);
    vec3 NormalMap = texture2D(u_normals, vTexCoord).rgb;


    vec3 LightDir = vec3(LightPos.x - gl_FragCoord.x/ Resolution.x,LightPos.y - gl_FragCoord.y / Resolution.y, LightPos.z);

    float D = length(LightDir);

    vec3 N = normalize(NormalMap * 2.0 - 1.0);
    float LRot = atan(LightDir.y, LightDir.x);
    vec3 L = normalize(vec3(cos(LRot + Rotation),sin(LRot + Rotation),LightDir.z + 0.5));

    vec3 Diffuse = (LightColor.rgb * LightColor.a) * max(dot(N, L), 0.0);

    vec3 Ambient = AmbientColor.rgb * AmbientColor.a;

    float Attenuation = 1.0 / ( Falloff.x + (Falloff.y*D) + (Falloff.z*D*D) );

    vec3 Intensity = 2 * Ambient + Diffuse * Attenuation;
    vec3 FinalColor = DiffuseColor.rgb * Intensity;
//sumColor gets added as many times as there are lights
    sumColor = sumColor + vColor * vec4(FinalColor, DiffuseColor.a);
    }
    gl_FragColor = sumColor;
}
```

Currently I pass the other Vectors into the .frag file using the setUniformf(String name, Vector3f v) method from the ShaderProgram class.
For Example, I would like to pass them in like:

```
public Vector3f[] lights;
//all the lights get add into the array
shader.setUniformf("Lights", lights);
```

It would be even more nice if I could store the lights in a ListArray<> and pass that into the fragment shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that is a problem with lighting in OpenGL. If you want to do what is called forward shading, you must have a limited amount of lights in your shader.
There are several ways to do more advanced lighting calculations and still have a good performance, one of them is deferred shading.

You can find a great article about this here http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Deferred-Shading

Unfortunately it uses c++, but i hope you can find some more information on how to do it using java.

Comment: I think that's true. Well, deferred lighting it is! Thanks for the fast answer!